# form submit redirect to a new url with AMP-HTML

Tags: query-string, amp-html

I have a simple problem yet it seems impossible to solve in AMP!!

I have a simple `form` with an `input` and a `submit button` like this:

```
<form id="myform">
     <input type="text" id="srchInput"/>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

All I want is to be able to concat a static url to the input value and redirect the page to the result, when the form is submitted.

For instance if the user inputs: `"Hello"` and submits the form, I would like to redirect him to a page like `"MY/STATIC/URL/Hello"`.

Is  there any way to achieve this in amp?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is via a GET action:

```
 <head>
  ...
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="GET" action="MY/STATIC/URL" target="_top">
   <input type="text" id="srchInput" name="srcInput" value="test">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
 </body>
```

The form submit will navigate to `/MY/STATIC/URL?srcInput=test`.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by setting the `AMP-Redirect-To` header in the response ([See AMP-form-redirection](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#redirecting-after-a-submission)). Send the user input on form submission, and then generate your desired url from your API endpoint and set `AMP-Redirect-To` header in your response to the generated URL.

Another way of doing it would be by using `navigateTo(url=STRING)` action ([See AMP Actions & Events](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events#target:-amp)) on for the form submit event. In this case you have to store the value in input to a state by using events like `input-throttled`, and then use url substitution in the `navigateTo` url string to append amp-state value.

The first method is guaranteed to work. 
The second method should work in theory, but I was unable to figure out how to get AMP-STATE value by url substitution. The code for the same should be something like:

```
<form id="myform" on="submit:AMP.navigateTo(url="MY/STATIC/URL/AMP_STATE(endValue)>")">

     <input type="text" id="srchInput" on="input-throttled:AMP.setState({ endValue : event.value })" />

     <button type="submit"> Submit </button>

</form>
```

If you can figure out how to substitute amp-state value to the url this should work. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Does not work. 

Errors:

The mandatory attribute 'action' is missing in tag 'FORM [method=GET]'.
The mandatory attribute 'target' is missing in tag 'FORM [method=GET]'.